# Why is my unit test trying to insert a record when I'm not asking it to?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, sqlite, unit-testing, devise, ruby-on-rails-5

I'm using rails 5 with devise.  I'm trying to write some unit tests for my controller, but am running into a wall.  Here's the method I'm trying to test

```
  # GET /issues/new
  def new
    unless user_signed_in?
      redirect_to new_user_session_path
    end
    @issue = Issue.new(stop_onestop_id: params[:stop_id], line_onestop_id: params[:line_id])
  end
```

and here's the test I'm writing

```
# issues_controller_test.rb
class IssuesControllerTest < ActionDispatch::IntegrationTest

  include Devise::Test::IntegrationHelpers

  test "logged in should get issues page" do
    sign_in users(:one)
    test_stop_id = 1
    test_line_id = 1
    get new_issue_url, params: {stop_id: test_stop_id, line_id: test_line_id}
    assert_equal test_stop_id, @issue.stop.id
    assert_equal test_line_id, @issue.line.id
    assert_response :success
  end
end
```

However, when I run it, I get the below exception ...

```
localhost:Caravan-App davea$ rails test
Running via Spring preloader in process 9509
Run options: --seed 48437

# Running:

E

Error:
IssuesControllerTest#test_logged_in_should_get_issues_page:
ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique: SQLite3::ConstraintException: UNIQUE constraint failed: users.email: INSERT INTO "users" ("created_at", "updated_at", "id") VALUES ('2017-12-27 19:07:16.234345', '2017-12-27 19:07:16.234345', 298486374)



bin/rails test test/controllers/issues_controller_test.rb:6



Finished in 0.320746s, 3.1177 runs/s, 0.0000 assertions/s.

1 runs, 0 assertions, 0 failures, 1 errors, 0 skips
```

No where am I asking for a new record to be created, so why is my test trying to insert one?

Comment: `users(:one)` is grabbing a test fixture. Have you checked your `users.yml` fixture file? You could have a couple fixtures there violating the unique email constraint.

Comment: Try changing `redirect_to new_user_session_path` to `redirect_to new_user_session_path and return`

Comment: @DerekHopper, Good call with taht fixtures file.  That was indeed the issue.

Comment: Isn't that only 1/2 of the problem? It seems like it shouldn't run ` @issue = Issue.new(stop_onestop_id: params[:stop_id], line_onestop_id: params[:line_id])` at all, unless user_signed_in?...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the line `sign_in users(:one)`, `users(:one)` is fetching a fixture. Seeing that tells me you're using a fixtures file.

There's a file `users.yml` in your project which defines some users for testing. It looks like the `ActiveRecord::RecordNotUnique` exception is coming from there. More specifically, a user fixture appears to be violating a uniqueness constraint on `users.email`.

If you fix your `users.yml` file by giving each user a unique email address, you should be good to go.